# Gmail push notification - empty history when Attached file exist

Tags: push-notification, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, webhooks

I'm using **Gmail [push notification](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)** in order to get user Gmail activities. It works well but I noticed a weird behavior that prevent me from getting the user sent email attached files

Each time I'm getting a push notification to my server endpoint, I'm sending GET request of [user history list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) using the historyId I received from the raised notification

when sending the history List request on email that sent **without** a file attachments I'm getting object response that contain the message Id

```
{"history":[{"id":"59237","messages":[{"id":"15eb563b63b660ed","threadId":"15eb563b63b660ed"}]}],"historyId":"59238"}
```

but when sending the history List request on email that sent **with** file attachments **I'm not getting the message Id and without it I cant get that message details along with the file attachments**

```
{"historyId":"59281"}
```

**what cause this behavior and what can I do to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems I didn't understand the flow of getting user history activities.
basically you need to save the HistoryId in the response when registering to webhook and use it to request [Users.history: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list).
the response include the activities info and also historyId that we need to save again - in order to use it next time we get notification about this user activity

another explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797416/gmail-api-users-watch-no-details-for-historyid)