# gmail api returning null for a specific history id. History id received from Cloud Pub/Sub push subscription

Tags: c#, gmail-api

From Cloud pub/sub push service i got a history id. Using that history id i am trying to read the recent mail's but It returns null.

I have configured cloud pub/sub push subscription and add a watch to "Unread" label.

Scenario 1:
I have received a push notification. From that push notification i have taken history id to get the recent messages. it's returning me null value.

Scenario 2:
I have logged into that configured mail id and then the message loaded in inbox. After that if i try to read i am getting the history list.

```
    static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     string UserId = "####.gmail.com";
     UserCredential credential;
     using (var stream =
                    new FileStream("client_secret_#####.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {             
                    string credPath = "token.json";
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        UserId,
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                }

     var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

     List<History> result = new List<History>();
                UsersResource.HistoryResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.History.List(UserId);
    //history id received from cloud pub/sub push subscription.
                request.StartHistoryId = Convert.ToUInt64("269871");

    do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ListHistoryResponse response = request.Execute();
                        if (response.History != null)
                        {
                            result.AddRange(response.History);
                        }
                        request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    }
                } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));


      foreach (var vHistory in result)
                {
                    foreach (var vMsg in vHistory.Messages)
                    {
                        string date = string.Empty;
                        string from = string.Empty;
                        string subject = string.Empty;
                        string body = string.Empty;

                        var emailInfoRequest = service.Users.Messages.Get(UserId, vMsg.Id);
                        var emailInfoResponse = emailInfoRequest.Execute();
                        if(emailInfoResponse!= null)
                        {
                            foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
                            {
                                if (mParts.Name == "Date")
                                {
                                    date = mParts.Value;
                                }
                                else if (mParts.Name == "From")
                                {
                                    from = mParts.Value;
                                }
                                else if (mParts.Name == "Subject")
                                {
                                    subject = mParts.Value;
                                }
                                if (date != "" && from != "")
                                {
                                    if (emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (MessagePart p in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts)
                                        {
                                            if (p.MimeType == "text/html")
                                            {
                                                byte[] data = FromBase64ForUrlString(p.Body.Data);
                                                body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                                            }
                                            else if(p.Filename!=null && p.Filename.Length>0)
                                            {
                                                string attId = p.Body.AttachmentId;
                                                string outputDir = @"D:\#####\";
                                                MessagePartBody attachPart = service.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get(UserId, vMsg.Id, attId).Execute();
                                                String attachData = attachPart.Data.Replace('-', '+');
                                                attachData = attachData.Replace('_', '/');
                                                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(attachData);
                                                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(outputDir, p.Filename), data);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        byte[] data = FromBase64ForUrlString(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body.Data);                                   
                                        body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
 public static byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
    {
        int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
        result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
        result.Replace('-', '+');
        result.Replace('_', '/');
        return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
    }

    }
```

Please let me know how to read the full message using history id. when i receive push notification.

Comment: I have found the answer. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797416/gmail-api-users-watch-no-details-for-historyid

Answer (score 0):

The [Gmail Api documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) states that the `Users.history:list` method requires `startHistoryId` as a parameter to be executed, rather than giving you this parameter as a response. This is confusing, since it states as an optional parameter, but it is also specifies that it is required. The documentation also specifies:

> The supplied startHistoryId should be obtained from the historyId of a
>   message, thread, or previous list response.

I suggest you to test the methods you use first with "Try this API" and [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). This makes it easier to understand which parameters you need to supply and which responses you can obtain from each method.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this. The point is that the `history_id` you are receiving is to be interpreted like the "latest moment when something happened". So, in order to make this work, you MUST use a `history_id` coming from a previous execution (that, don't forget, in GMail Push API means that you have to implement the initial *full sync*, or at the very least you should be executing a second run of your *partial sync*), which will return the events that span from the previous `history_id` to the one you just received.

I have just published an article on medium, since the detail of the `history_id`, in my opinion, can be a little sneaky. Article is [here](https://medium.com/@brunoripa/g-suite-domain-wide-authority-delegation-elixir-pubsub-91c00a3918c).